# Deduce dielectric function from appearance of material

Tags: optics

It is often hard to find data on the optical absorption spectra of materials. However one can easily find a description of the appearence of a material (e.g. grey powder, white powder, metallic). What and to what degree can you deduce the imaginary part of the dielectric function from this information?

My ideas are:

- white/transparant powder: Insulator or semiconductor with band gap larger or roughly equal to 3 eV. $\varepsilon_2 =0$ in the whole optical range.
- colored powder: relatively low absorption in the missing colors of its appearence (e.g. red powder $\Rightarrow$ absorption in the blue range)
- Metallic, silvery: high $\varepsilon_2$ in the whole optical range
- Metallic, golden: high $\varepsilon_2$ in the whole optical range, but smaller for low wavelengths.
- Grey powder: relatively low $\varepsilon_2$ in the whole optical range